# Windows 8.1 Asus G711JW - Lag on maximizing some apps

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, lag

Applications like Chrome and Skype, etc get a lot of FPS (Frames per second) dropping when the window takes more than 70% of the screen area, maximizing it gives me about 20 fps on scrolling and interacting with it. If I resize it's so it is less than 50% it gives me a whopping 60+fps. Any solutions?

Comment: So what graphics hardware do you have? Are you able to get good FPS on full-screen games at the same or higher resolutions?

Comment: I found the solution and posted it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update drivers at support.asus.com and NOT asus.com. There are two seperate driver pages and the asus.com one is outdated and will give you the broken driver. This will also fix scrolling lag, transparency bug with windows and overall performance.

I found this solution after digging a bit. It's dumb that Asus doesn't remove the old page for drivers, because it was really frustrating to think it wasn't updated. Oh well, problem solved!